# "import cycle not allowed" while running test in golang example

Tags: go

I'm trying to setup tests for my functions in golang, but getting the following error while running `go test ...` from the console:

> import cycle not allowed package runtime
>           imports unsafe
>           imports runtime

Thinking that it was me I cloned the [golang example project](https://github.com/golang/example) and ran `go test reverse_test.go`, but getting the same error.
Both my `GOPATH` and `GOROOT` environment values are set to `C:\go`, where I installed Go.
I'm on a Windows 8.1, 64bit machine.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: "Both my GOPATH and GOROOT environment values are set to C:\go" Wait, what? You never do that. GOPATH is where your projects are (a "workspace"), not where go is installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to do a "`go get github.com/golang/example/hello`" (as mentioned in [github.com/golang/example](https://github.com/golang/example)) once your GOPATH is set to a proper path.

See "[How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH)":

> The `GOPATH` environment variable specifies the location of your workspace. It is likely the only environment variable you'll need to set when developing Go code.

You should see your `github/golang/example` inside `$GOPATH/src`